# Getting ORA-00913 on really big IN clauses

Tags: oracle, select

I am trying to build an SQL query with around 100.000 given values.

For example:

```
Given values = [1, 2, 4, 5, 30, ...]
```

And I want to select all elements with an ID matching one of the elements.

I tried it like this:

```sql
SELECT x FROM y WHERE
  someOtherColumn = 'test'
  AND (
   id = 1
   OR id = 2
   OR id = 4
   OR id = 5
   OR id = 30
   -- ... 
 );
```

And like this:

```sql
SELECT x FROM y WHERE
  someOtherColumn = 'test'
  AND (
   id IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 30, ...) --- 1000 values per IN clause
   OR id IN (...)
   -- ... 
 );
```

Both give me the same Error:

> ORA-00913: Zu viele Werte

Is there another way to do this?

## This is not a 1000 Limit in `IN` clause issue!

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be anything to do with the IDs or the IN list limit. Do you still get it if you remove the `AND ( ... )` completely? It's more likely to be in a part of a query you haven't shown, like a subquery that returns multiple values.

Comment: No I don't get the same error if I remove the AND part completely. The query is working fine otherwise. @AlexPoole

Answer (score 0):

Where do the values for your IN clause originate?  Load your values into a reference table, then select that in your IN clause.

```
create ref_table (ref_value varchar2(20);
insert into ref_table ('1');
insert into ref_table ('2');

SELECT x FROM y WHERE
  someOtherColumn = 'test'
  AND (
   id IN (select ref_value from ref_table);
```

Comment: They are from some webservice I call. Do you think performance will suffer hard, when putting in 100k rows with a single column? Also, `IN` allows a maximum of 1000 values - does this not apply here?

Comment: Performance?  How is your performance now, with a statement that throws an error?  Get it to actually work.  THEN you can worry about performance.  The 1000 element limit only applies for a hard-coded list.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I still worry about performance before I get it to work though, because I already have it working.